# Play framework: JDBC connection vs JDBC datasource

Tags: java, database, jdbc, playframework

I'm new to the Play! framework and I was looking at ways to connect to a DB.

In the docs there is 2 ways to get a JDBC connection, one using the DB.getDatasource() and one using the DB.getConnection() method: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaDatabase

What is the difference between each? Pros and Cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConnection()` in Play Java eventually calls the `getConnection` function from a `DBApi` implementation in the Play Scala library that looks like this:

```
def getConnection(name: String, autocommit: Boolean = true): Connection = {
    val connection = getDataSource(name).getConnection
    connection.setAutoCommit(autocommit)
    connection
}
```

This is just calling `getDataSource` and then retrieving a connection from it.

`getDataSource()` returns a [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html), which as you can see the the Java API docs doesn't give you all that much to do but get a connection from it. Unless you need slightly more fine grained control, `getConnection()` should suffice.